# Ban command not working JDA please help debuged and everything

Tags: discord-jda

Hello so i am making a bot in JDA and i just made a ban command but it aint banning anyone the code is
i mention the user and also put a reason and put the user id and still make no difference

```
package me.programmer.CodeDevelopment.Commands;

import me.programmer.CodeDevelopment.Bot;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.Permission;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class Ban extends ListenerAdapter {


    public void onMessageGuildReceived(List<String> args, GuildMessageReceivedEvent e){
        String msg = e.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase(Bot.PREFIX + "ban")){
            TextChannel channel = e.getChannel();
            Member member = e.getMember();
            List<Member> mentionedMembers = e.getMessage().getMentionedMembers();

            if (mentionedMembers.isEmpty() || args.size() < 2) {
                channel.sendMessage("Missing Arguments").queue();
                return;
            }

            Member target = mentionedMembers.get(0);
            String reason = String.join(" ", args.subList(1, args.size()));

            if (!member.hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS) && !member.canInteract(target)){
                channel.sendMessage("You dont have pmerission to run this command").queue();
                return;
            }

            target.ban(1)
                    .reason(String.format("Ban by: %#s, with reason: %s", e.getAuthor(), reason)).queue();
        }

    }



}
```

Please help i have been stuck on this for a little while.

Comment: You didn't override the method from ListenerAdapter properly. The name and parameter list has to match.

Comment: already tried that and doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Like Minn mentioned, You didn't override the method from ListenerAdapter properly. The name and parameter list have to match.

Also, You're checking if the entire message is equal to `{PREFIX}ban` yet your ban command is structured like so `{PREFIX}ban (user)` so your code always stops on this line:

```
    if(msg.equalsIgnoreCase(Bot.PREFIX + "ban"))
```

Because that is never true when using the command correctly.

This should work instead (I've changed the msg check to starts with from equals, I've changed the method name to the right one with the right parameters from `ListenerAdapter` and I've then kept your usage of args by splitting the `msg` string and putting that into a list):

```
public class Ban extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e) {
        String msg = e.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        if (msg.startsWith(Bot.PREFIX + "ban")) {
            TextChannel channel = e.getChannel();
            Member member = e.getMember();
            List<Member> mentionedMembers = e.getMessage().getMentionedMembers();

            List<String> args = Arrays.asList(msg.split(" "));
            if (mentionedMembers.isEmpty() || args.size() < 2) {
                channel.sendMessage("Missing Arguments").queue();
                return;
            }

            Member target = mentionedMembers.get(0);
            String reason = String.join(" ", args.subList(1, args.size()));

            if (!member.hasPermission(Permission.BAN_MEMBERS) && !member.canInteract(target)) {
                channel.sendMessage("You dont have pmerission to run this command").queue();
                return;
            }

            target.ban(1)
                    .reason(String.format("Ban by: %#s, with reason: %s", e.getAuthor(), reason)).queue();
        }
    }
}
```